# Inline Ternary Operator Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, ternary-operator

For some reason my ternary operator assignment isn't work for the second part of my array. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Its supposed to just see if there is a value for the permalink field and if there isn't then insert the `link_url` into the array.

```
function getSiteMap()
{
    $this->db->select('site_menu_structures_links.id, site_menu_structures_links.link_name');
    $this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links');
    $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links.status_id', 1); 
    $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links.is_category', 'Yes'); 
    $this->db->order_by('site_menu_structures_links.sort_order'); 
    $catQuery = $this->db->get();

    if ($catQuery->num_rows())
    {
        foreach ($catQuery->result() as $cats)
        {
            // Set the Main Category into the array
            $testArray[$cats->id] = array(
                'id'   => $cats->id,
                'name' =>$cats->link_name
            );

            $this->db->select('site_content_pages.permalink, site_menu_structures_links_children.id, site_menu_structures_links_children.link_url, site_menu_structures_links_children.link_name');
            $this->db->from('site_menu_structures_links_children');
            $this->db->join('site_content_pages', 'site_content_pages.id = site_menu_structures_links_children.site_content_pages_id');
            $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_id', $cats->id); 
            $this->db->where('site_menu_structures_links_children.status_id', 1);  
            $this->db->order_by('site_menu_structures_links_children.sort_order'); 
            $childrenQuery = $this->db->get();



            if ($childrenQuery->num_rows())
            {
                foreach ($childrenQuery->result() as $child)
                {
                    $testArray[$cats->id]['children'][$child->id] = array(
                        'linke_url' => (empty($child->permalink)) ? $child->link_url : $child->permalink,
                        'link_name' => $child->link_name,
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $testArray;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also not that there should be 3 items inside the Social Array and its not saying there is. I'm wondering if it has something to do with that join. Here's my output:

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Roster
        [children] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Superstars
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Champions and Contenders
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Title History
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Events
        [children] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Preview Next Event
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Latest Event Results
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Event Archives
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Schedule An Event
                    )

            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Media
        [children] => Array
            (
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [linke_url] => 
                        [link_name] => Photo Gallery
                    )

            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Social
    )

 )
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be `linke_url`? You're presumably not trying to access `link_url` or something and it's a typo? I can't see anything wrong with the code other than I'd have thought it'd error because of the comma after $child->link_name but it might not. Do you get any PHP errors, probably notably errors of type `NOTICE` in this case.

Comment: Also, am I to understand that you're trying to build a hierarchy of categories and `site_menu_structures_links_id` is the parent id internally referencing `site_menu_structures_links.id`- if so, this can be _massively optimised_

Comment: Can you post an example of input and output? We need to know what's expected and what's happening to help you figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have:

```
'linke_url' => (empty($child->permalink)) ? $child->link_url : $child->permalink,
```

I'll assume you meant `'link_url'` and not `'linke_url'`, so it looks like you're trying to do:

If `$child->permalink` is empty, set `'link_url'` to `$child->link_url`, but, if `$child->permalink` isn't empty, set `'link_url'` to `$child->permalink`.

I would recommend using the shorthand version of the [ternary operator ?:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which is the form: `$a = $b ?: $c` which is the same as if `$b` evaluates to `true`, i.e. if `$b` has any value, `$a = $b`, otherwise `$a = $c`.  For you:

```
'link_url' => $child->permalink ?: $child->link_url
```

If `$child->permalink` has a value, that will be used, otherwise, the value of `$child->link_url` will be used.  Good luck!

Comment: Be warned that shorthand ternary is only available as of 5.3

Comment: @BenSwinburne is right; this is only available in 5.3+ and the equivalent for earlier versions is the slightly longer: `'link_url' => $child_permalink ? $child->permalink : $child->link_url`