# Using IF ELSE within an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, constants

I need to add a IF ELSE within an array but I am having issues to get the right syntax.

Here is the original snippet:

```
function init(){
    // I18n
    load_plugin_textdomain($this->text_domain, false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/../languages/');
    $this->javascriptVariables = array(
                                'more'  => __('More Results', $this->text_domain),
                                'empty' => __('0 results', $this->text_domain),
                                'char_number' => get_option('search_in_place_minimum_char_number'),
                                'root'   => get_site_url(),
                                'home' => trim( get_settings('home')+ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, "0"),
                        );

} // End init
```

What I need is relatively simple:
 You see the line "'more'  => __('More Results', $this->text_domain),"

Well, I need that if the page language is English, then the value is "More Results", if it is Italian then the value must be "Mostra tutto", etc.

The language code is available from a constant called  ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE
So if ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==en  then 'more' should ahve the value "Show More, if ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=it the value is etc etc.

I tried using IF ELSE both within the array and also outside but with no result.

Can you please help me with this? 
I really appreciate it.

Comment: you can try with [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235904/inline-ternary-operator-not-working)

Comment: Do you know what the function `__` in the code does? Its purpose is *specifically* to select localized text based on the language, although exactly how it works would be specific to your application environment. So what you need to do is not add an `if`, but learn how to use `__`.

Comment: I also just noticed that the code reads `get_settings('home')+ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE`. Whoever wrote that needs to stop programming in PHP right now and go back to the basics class.

Comment: Jon, please be more constructive: people learn by making mistakes or thanks to good teachers. Good teacher are never asking students to stop trying.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of all translated messages for all languages and use lookup instead of `if` statement:

```
$messages = array()
$messages['more_results'] = array('en'=>'More results', 'it' => 'Mostra tutto');
```

Instead of `'More Results'` you will have something like `$messages['more_results'][$ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE]`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator:

```
  $this->javascriptVariables = array(
                                'more'  => __(($ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "it") ? 'Mostra tutto' : 'More results',, $this->text_domain),
                                'empty' => __('0 results', $this->text_domain),
                                'char_number' => get_option('search_in_place_minimum_char_number'),
                                'root'   => get_site_url(),
                                'home' => trim( get_settings('home')+ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, "0"),
                        );
```

**Alternative Solution:**

You can check the language first and then use that in your array.

```
if($ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "Italian"){ //pseudo code
$word = "Mostra tutto";
}
else{
$word = "More Results";
}
```

And, then use that variable in your array, like so:

```
$this->javascriptVariables = array(
                            'more'  => __($word, $this->text_domain),                              
                            'empty' => __('0 results', $this->text_domain),
                            'char_number' => get_option('search_in_place_minimum_char_number'),
                            'root'   => get_site_url(),
                            'home' => trim( get_settings('home')+ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, "0"),
                    );
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I tested it I don't see the expected result: the string is always displayed in English. What could I be missing?

Answer (score -1):

I thik the better way was doing this before a insertion to array.
ex:

```
function init(){
    // I18n
    load_plugin_textdomain($this->text_domain, false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/../languages/');

    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE='it')
        $world = 'Mostra Tutto';
    elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE='en')
        $world = 'More Results';
    // etc.
    $this->javascriptVariables = array(
                            'more'  => __($world, $this->text_domain),
                            'empty' => __('0 results', $this->text_domain),
                            'char_number' => get_option('search_in_place_minimum_char_number'),
                            'root'   => get_site_url(),
                            'home' => trim( get_settings('home')+ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, "0"),
                    );

} // End init
```

Hope i help you, let me know ;) 
(p.s. sorry for bad English)